# Using Eloquent ORM from Laravel 4 outside of Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I created a folder 'eloquent' to start testing/learning the component, and my **composer.json** file is:

```
{
  "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.0",
    "illuminate/database": "4.0.*"
  }
}
```

Below is my **test.php** file, with credentials removed.  It works great, until I add ->remember(10) into the command.  I'd like to look into adding the Illuminate Cache next then, if that's what's needed to start using ->remember().  Is anyone aware of any blog posts or tutorials on doing something like this?

```
<?php
/**
 * Testing Laravel's Eloquent ORM
 * @see https://github.com/illuminate/database
 * @see http://laravel.com/docs/database
 */
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;

$capsule = new Capsule;

$capsule->addConnection(array(
  'driver'    => '',
  'host'      => '',
  'database'  => '',
  'username'  => '',
  'password'  => '',
  'charset'   => 'utf8',
  'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
  'prefix'    => '',
  ));

//$capsule->bootEloquent();
$capsule->setAsGlobal();

$name = Capsule::table('user')->where('id', 123 )->remember(10)->get();

var_dump( $name );

// PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ReflectionException' with message 'Class cache does not exist'
```

I'm not sure what the next step is to get **->remember()** working.  I tried adding **illuminate/cache** to the composer.json file and updated.  I wasn't sure how to use it with Eloquent, outside of Laravel.

Comment: Maybe this gist will help you: https://gist.github.com/clauddiu/4234104

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should already be pulling in "illuminate/cache", look in vendor and you should see it there.

You need to setup the cache manager, then pass that through by calling

```
$capsule->setCacheManager(CacheManager $cache);
```

I've not looked under the hood for details on how to do this but hopefully this will be enough details to get you going forward.

**Edit:**

Here's what you need to add to get it working:

```
use Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager as CacheManager;

$container = $capsule->getContainer();

$container->offsetGet('config')->offsetSet('cache.driver', 'array');

$cacheManager = new CacheManager($container);

$capsule->setCacheManager($cacheManager);
```

Obviously feel free to change the Cache Driver used but keep in mind that changing the Cache Driver will require adding the extra required settings.

Comment: saf33r, thanks for the lead.  btw, fan of your blog.  Maybe you could cover this topic and show how to setup other cache drivers?

Answer (score 5):

saff33r  is right,  but just to help someone like me that need "file" cache this is how to:
in your composer.json

```
    "illuminate/cache": "4.0.*",
    "illuminate/filesystem": "4.0.*",
```

in your boot file:

```
    use \Illuminate\Database\Capsule\Manager as Capsule;
    use \Illuminate\Cache\CacheManager as CacheManager;
    use \Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem as Filesystem;
    ...

    $container = $capsule->getContainer();
    $container['config']['cache.driver'] = 'file';
    $container['config']['cache.path'] = __DIR__ . '/uploads/cache/eloquent';
    $container['config']['cache.connection'] = null;
    $container['files'] = new Filesystem();

    $cacheManager = new CacheManager($container);
    $capsule->setCacheManager($cacheManager);
    $capsule->bootEloquent();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/Luracast/Laravel-Database it provides full eloquent support outside laravel including artisan migrations and more﻿

- `4.2` branch contains laravel 4.2.* components
- `5.2` branch contains laravel 5.2.* components

> Disclosure: I'm the author of the above repository